# in C - return values to a function several times "at once"

Tags: c, return-value

The question is, how can return values to a function several times inside the same "**case**"?

The `fork()` call will cause each of the return statements to execute once, how does the parent function containing the `case` return?

The idea looks like this:

```
  case 15:
    if((bufLen == 15) && ((buf[0] & 0x80) == 128)) {  
      int rx = buf[5]; 
      int tx = buf[6];    
      pid_t demux = fork (2);
      if (demux == 0) {
          (*arity)++; 
          return append_int(outBuf, outLen, outSz, "RX", rx)      
      }
      if (demux > 0) {
          (*arity)++;     
          return append_int(outBuf, outLen, outSz, "TX", tx);     
      }
    }
    break; // case 15
```

Where the target function has the following parameters form:

```
append_int(char *buf, int off, int bufsz, char *key, int val);
```

The important requirement is that it has to be done within the "**case**" as "storing" data and "going back" to retrieve it is not an option due to the amount of received frames.

So far, an applied solution leads to high usage of resources in the long run. Trying to kill child processes led to zombies which in the long run also generates dodgy behavior with the resources.

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: It seems like a perfect opportunity to use the secret language feature called "variables".

Comment: What is the `2` in `fork(2)` supposed to be? `fork()` doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Forking seems like a really bad idea here -- are you sure that's what you want to do?  (I'm not surprised you're having problems with zombies and other "dodgy behavior".)

Comment: @Barmar Probably from "man fork(2)" ....

Answer (score 2):

In C each function can only return once. Any code after the first return statement will never be run. If you wish to have multiple outputs from a function you have two options:

1) Provide the output values via pointers or references that get passed to the function as parameters.

2) Have a struct return type and populate the values of the struct as your function progresses and then return the populated struct once at the end of your function's execution path.

Comment: If yuo look at the more complete code, he's not actually trying to return multiple times. They're inside different `if` blocks, so only one of them will be executed.